# UIKit: How to stop hiding the child (Button), when we hide the parent UIView (myView)

Tags: swift, button, uiview, uikit, hidden

I have a UIView and there is a button inside the UIView.

When I am hiding the UIView, the button inside the UIView is also hidden.

But I want to hide the UIView but not the Button at the same time. The Code I wrote to hide the UIView (named "myView") is given below:

`myView.isHidden = true`

Comment: Hiding a view hides all its subviews. If you need the button to remain visible you need to change your view hierarchy so that the button is not a subview of the view you want to hide.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I am looking for a solution, where I do not need to change the hierarchy.

Comment: Hiding a parent view will always hide its subviews (and its subviews’ subviews). That is just just the way iOS works. You could achieve a similar visual appearance by hiding all of the parent view’s subviews except for the button. But that is a workaround to achieve the same appearance (and will still allow any gesture recognisers on the parent view to work). You will not be hiding the parent view at all in this workaround.

Answer (score -1):

The button is the subview of the view. It will be hidden after hiding the view. But there is a workaround that I did: I simply set the background colour of the view with a low alpha component. That will make the view transparent, and the button will also be visible.

```
yourView.backgroundColor = UIColor.colourofyourView.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
```

I think this will solve your problem.